# After trying operators like strip, I still have space in front of multiple lines of printed results in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a print section and the code is:

```
print(firstname,"\n",
      lastname,"\n",
      address,"\n",
      nationality,"\n",
      cellphone,"\n",
      homephone)
```

The values for the variables don't have space. And I got the results:

```
Amy 
 Chen 
 123 Alberta St. 
 US 
 1234 
 5678
```

The result that I want should be like:

```
Amy 
Chen 
123 Alberta St. 
US 
1234 
5678
```

I tried operators like .strip and .rstrip etc. to remove the space in front of each variable:

```
print(firstname.strip(),"\n",
      lastname.strip(),"\n",
      address.strip(),"\n",
      nationality.strip(),"\n",
      cellphone.strip(),"\n",
      homephone.strip())
```

But the result is the same. Can anyone tell me the reason for this and the solution? Thank you

Comment: What you don't actually see is there is a space inserted after `every` comma by default, so your lines are actually `firstname \n`, ` lastname \n`, etc.  Using Python3 I would go with @jason's or @gill's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `print` accepts an optional `sep` argument, which controls what gets printed between any two values, and it defaults to a space. While @Jason's answer is correct, you basically need a newline between the values. So just set `sep` to `\n`:

```
print(firstname,
      lastname,
      address,
      nationality,
      cellphone,
      homephone,
      sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `print('\n'.join([firstname, lastname, address, nationality, cellphone, homephone]))`?

Answer (score 0):

print firstname,"\n",lastname,"\n",address,"\n",nationality